# How to display post meta data in secure manner

Tags: themes, post-meta, security, escaping

I have have a custom post meta field where I can add a embedding code (a video for example, an iframe). Now I want to retrieve the code from the post meta and display it securely.

I can display it like this:

```
$embed_code = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_embed_code', true);
echo $embed_code;
```

It works correctly and displays the video. However if I use the `esc_html` like:

```
echo esc_html( $embed_code );
```

it does not work. It displays the code on the page, it does not render it. So how can I display the above code in a secure manner.

Comment: I think that correct approach in this case is not escaping the data, it is validate the data when you retrieve it, not when display it.

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on how you define *secure*.

I assume your embed code is an iframe which means that you are putting something not under your control (that could in theory always change into something malicious) into your site. This isn't 100% secure itself. That is why `esc_html` strips that out.

The question you have to ask yourself is how much of a risk this is regarding the person who has the right to change this field.

But maybe there is an alternative if the embed you are using is from [a site that has oEmbed support in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#Okay.2C_So_What_Sites_Can_I_Embed_From.3F).

Then you can easily embed it using [wp_oembed_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get). This still puts an iframe from somewhere else into your site, but at least it doesn't allow arbitrary HTML or JS.

If you add some more info about what embed code we are actually talking about I might even be able to provide an example.